# Why does Panel make my view collapse when SelectOneMenu is clicked?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click on my `<p:selectOneMenu>` the whole layout crashes. When I click outside the menu and then the menu itself again, always the layout changes. When I remove the `<p:panel>` the problem is gone. I see the problem is the `<p:panel>` in combination with the `<h:panelGrid>`.

How to avoid the behavior?
See my gif below!

Additional Information:

- Primefaces 6.0
- Primefaces "Omega" Theme

[image]

Here is my minimal code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:panel header="panel">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

                    <h:panelGrid id="wfSelectionGrid" columns="2" >
                        <h:outputText value="Category:" />
                        <p:selectOneButton >

                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                        </p:selectOneButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <p:outputLabel for="wfSelectionMenu" value="Anwendungsfall:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="wfSelectionMenu">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="AA" itemValue="AA" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="BB" itemValue="BB" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="CC" itemValue="CC" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:commandButton id="defineXmlButton" value="to stuff" />

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:**
Broken down to less code, even the following sample leads to the problem:

```
        <h:form>
                    <p:panel header="panel">

                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <p:outputLabel for="wfSelectionMenu" value="Anwendungsfall:" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="wfSelectionMenu">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="AA" itemValue="AA" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="BB" itemValue="BB" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CC" itemValue="CC" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

**Edit 2:**
Adding colors makes it more visible which of the components change during the on click event. Now by using the attribute `cellspacing` and setting it to zero, the problem is gone. But is there another (better) solution?

```
           <p:panel header="panel" style="background-color:blue;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="background-color:red;"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <p:outputLabel for="wfSelectionMenu" value="Anwendungsfall:" style="background-color:green;" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="wfSelectionMenu" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="AA" itemValue="AA" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="BB" itemValue="BB" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="CC" itemValue="CC" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
```

**Edit 3:**
Using devtools - the interesting html component sizes are:

the `<td>` is `117*28 + 10` padding each side..
After the click its `115*28 + 10` padding each side.
Why is the component loosing those `2 px`? It seems that every other component stays the same size.

Comment: Tried giving theselectonemenu a value attribute that points to a real bean? Your code is non-functional as it stands now. Also tried a differwnt theme? Different (older) PF version?

Comment: The code is non-functional because I wanted to share an easy to test example. My real code points to real beans. The problem is the same in both cases (real and test case). I also removed my own stylesheet and removed the PF theme which still leads to the same behavior. I did not try changing the PF version. 
Now my workaround is, like I mentioned in "Edit 2", to set cellspacing to zero in the panelgrid.